# Yii2: query across two databases

Tags: oracle, activerecord, yii2

I have two databases (one in Oracle and one mySQL) and I somehow need to join the data.

The following query works:

```
$qry = oracleTableName::find()
  ->with('mysqlTableName')
  ->asArray()
  ->all();
```

and returns the following layout:

```
 [0]=> array(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => test
    [mysqlID] => 7
    [mysqlTableName] => array(
       [id]=>7
       [score]=>1
    )
  )
```

However, if I use the select statement, it fails, (saying that the column mysqlTableName.id is an invalid identifier):

```
$qry = oracleTableName::find()
  ->with('mysqlTableName')
  ->select([
       'oracleTableName.id as OracleID',
       'mysqlTableName.id as MysqlID',
       'mysqlTableName.score as Score'
   ])
  ->asArray()
  ->all();
```

How can I select from both databases (or "access" the mysql result) so that I have one output i.e.:

```
[0]=>array(
  [OracleID]=>1
  [MysqlID]=>7
  [Score]=>3
```

Thank you

### UPDATE

Here is the actual query and outputs:
NOTE: in this example, the table "MapInvestorToOpportunity" is mysql and the table "INVESTOR" is Oracle

This works fine:

```
$performance= MapInvestorToOpportunity::find()
    ->with('investor') 
    ->andWhere(['fk_opportunityID' => $this->fk_opportunityID])
    ->limit(5)
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

And yields the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 43797
            [uid] => 0451/0258_DD45834-99207
            [fk_opportunityID] => 3
            [status] => 1
            [fk_investorID] => 99207
            [investor] => Array
                (
                    [INVESTOR_ID] => 99207
                    [COUNTRY_ID] => US
                    [PRIMARY_INSTITUTION] => DD71233
```

I can clearly see the country ID. However, as soon as I select the country ID it fails:

```
$performance= MapInvestorToOpportunity::find()
    ->with('investor') // or ('investor INVESTOR')
    ->andWhere(['fk_opportunityID' => $this->fk_opportunityID])
    ->select([
         'fk_opportunityID',
         'fk_investorID',
         'map_investor_to_opportunity.INVESTOR_ID',
         'COUNTRY_ID', // or 'INVESTOR.COUNTRY_ID'
     ])
    ->limit(5)
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'INVESTOR.COUNTRY_ID' in 'field list'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `fk_opportunityID`, `fk_investorID`, `INVESTOR`.`COUNTRY_ID` FROM `map_investor_to_opportunity` WHERE `fk_opportunityID`='3' LIMIT 5
```

My understanding is that it is not possible to join the data in a query because it is two different databases. However, I just wanted to make absolutely sure... it seems a little crazy considering the array output clearly shows the data from the Oracle database

Many thanks

Comment: This is pure speculation, I apologize in advance if it is not helpful. Oracle is case sensitive, did you try making it `ORACLETABLENAME.ID`?

Comment: You could create a database link from Oracle to MySQL and join it all in the Oracle SQL engine. Sample from this source: https://hs2n.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/oracle-create-database-link-to-mysql-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to create JOIN between two completely separate DBMS. `with()` will register eager loading rules, but it will not create actual join between two tables - it will perform two separate queries to obtain necessary models.

To create actual join you should use [`joinWith()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail) instead of [`with()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#with()-detail).

```
$qry = oracleTableName::find()
  ->joinWith('mysqlTableName')
  ->select([
       'oracleTableName.id as OracleID',
       'mysqlTableName.id as MysqlID',
       'mysqlTableName.score as Score'
   ])
  ->asArray()
  ->all();
```

But this will most likely fail, since there is no support for cross-DB joins.

Probably the best what you could get is to query results separately and combine them at PHP level.

Comment: Thanks rob006 - I think you are right. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add a table identifier after the table name.

```
$qry = oracleTableName::find()
  ->with('mysqlTableName msql')
  ->select([
       'oracleTableName.id as OracleID',
       'msql.id as MysqlID',
       'msql.score as Score'
   ])
  ->asArray()
  ->all();
```

The reason for this is, the `with` clause accepts relation name, not Table name, which might be slightly, but enough different. If this doesn't work, please comment with the result of this query and I will edit the answer accordingly

```
$qry = oracleTableName::find()
      ->with('mysqlTableName msql')
      ->select([
           'oracleTableName.id as OracleID',
           'msql.id as MysqlID',
           'msql.score as Score'
       ])
      ->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin - I have updated my post. Your suggestion did not work.

Comment: @DrBorrow Have you tried to access it via `map_investor_to_opportunity.COUNTRY_ID` the same way you call `INVESTOR_ID`. They are both in the same scope. Also, on the side, if you do not strictly require for it to be an array, you can access it via `$performance->investor->COUNTRY_ID`. Please, tell me if this works.